# How to add dictionary (list object) to dictionary object in Python

Tags: python, odoo

here is my error when i going to do that in my code

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Here is my python dictionary list object.
in my code **tea_list_data**

```
[
{'bpl_division_id': 1, 'over_kgs': 2, 'worker_id': 1, 'names': 6.0, 'date': '2013-05-08', 'pss': 30.0, 
 'bpl_estate_id': 1, 'scrap': 3, 'bpl_company_id': 1, 'output': 15, 'type': 'tea'},
{'bpl_division_id': 1, 'over_kgs': 2, 'worker_id': 2, 'names': 6.0, 'date': '2013-05-08', 'pss': 30.0, 
'bpl_estate_id': 1, 'scrap': 3, 'bpl_company_id': 1, 'output': 15, 'type': 'tea'}, 
 'bpl_estate_id': 1, 'scrap': 3, 'bpl_company_id': 1, 'output': 15, 'type': 'rubber'}
]
```

And i need to change it to this type dictionary object.because i need to create records in openerp with some conditions.

below show my required output

```
{'bpl_division_id': 1, 'over_kgs': 2, 'worker_id': 1, 'names': 6.0, 'date': '2013-05-08', 'pss': 30.0, 
 'bpl_estate_id': 1, 'scrap': 3, 'bpl_company_id': 1, 'output': 15, 'type': 'tea'},
{'bpl_division_id': 1, 'over_kgs': 2, 'worker_id': 2, 'names': 6.0, 'date': '2013-05-08', 'pss': 30.0, 
'bpl_estate_id': 1, 'scrap': 3, 'bpl_company_id': 1, 'output': 15, 'type': 'tea'}, 
{'bpl_division_id': 1, 'over_kgs': 2, 'worker_id': 3, 'names': 6.0, 'date': '2013-05-08', 'pss': 30.0, 
'bpl_estate_id': 1, 'scrap': 3, 'bpl_company_id': 1, 'output': 15, 'type': 'rubber'}, 
{'bpl_division_id': 1, 'over_kgs': 2, 'worker_id': 4, 'names': 6.0, 'date': '2013-05-08', 'pss': 30.0, 
 'bpl_estate_id': 1, 'scrap': 3, 'bpl_company_id': 1, 'output': 15, 'type': 'rubber'}
```

please help me to sort this issue.

here shows my python code that i used to create above **1st result**

```
def temp_posting(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
    tea_v = {}
    tea_list_data = []

    if context is None:
        context = {}
    bpl_division_id = context['bpl_division_id']
    work_update_ids = self.pool.get('bpl.work.update').search(cr, uid, [('bpl_division_id', '=', bpl_division_id)])
    work_update_obj = self.pool.get('bpl.work.update').browse(cr, uid, work_update_ids)[0]
    if work_update_obj:
        work_update_obj.write({'state': 'negotiation'})        

    for record in work_update_obj.selected_tea_workers_update_line_ids:
        tea_list_data.append({'bpl_company_id': record.work_id.bpl_company_id.id, 'bpl_estate_id': record.work_id.bpl_estate_id.id, 'bpl_division_id': record.work_id.bpl_division_id.id, 'worker_id': record.worker_id.id, 'date': record.work_id.offered_date, 'type':'tea', 'names': 6.00, 'output':record.tea_total_kgs, 'over_kgs':2, 'scrap':3, 'pss':30.00})
    for record in work_update_obj.selected_rubber_workers_update_line_ids:
        tea_list_data.append({'bpl_company_id': record.work_id.bpl_company_id.id, 'bpl_estate_id': record.work_id.bpl_estate_id.id, 'bpl_division_id': record.work_id.bpl_division_id.id, 'worker_id': record.worker_id.id, 'date': record.work_id.offered_date, 'type':'rubber', 'names': 6.00, 'output':record.rubber_total_kgs, 'over_kgs':2, 'scrap':3, 'pss':30.00})    
    for record in work_update_obj.selected_sundry_workers_update_line_ids:
        tea_list_data.append({'bpl_company_id': record.work_id.bpl_company_id.id, 'bpl_estate_id': record.work_id.bpl_estate_id.id, 'bpl_division_id': record.work_id.bpl_division_id.id, 'worker_id': record.worker_id.id, 'date': record.work_id.offered_date, 'type':'sundry', 'names':record.sundry_hrs_worked, })    
    for record in work_update_obj.selected_other_workers_update_line_ids:
        tea_list_data.append({'bpl_company_id': record.work_id.bpl_company_id.id, 'bpl_estate_id': record.work_id.bpl_estate_id.id, 'bpl_division_id': record.work_id.bpl_division_id.id, 'worker_id': record.worker_id.id, 'date': record.work_id.offered_date, })
    tea_v = {tea_list_data}

    daily_transaction_master = self.pool.get('bpl.daily.transaction.master')
    daily_transaction_master.create(cr, uid, tea_v, context=context)
    return True
```

**EDITED**
**@Arya** please give your attention here

```
for record in work_update_obj.selected_tea_workers_update_line_ids:
    tea_list_data.append({'bpl_company_id': record.work_id.bpl_company_id.id, 'bpl_estate_id': record.work_id.bpl_estate_id.id, 'bpl_division_id': record.work_id.bpl_division_id.id, 'worker_id': record.worker_id.id, 'date': record.work_id.offered_date, 'type':'tea', 'names': 6.00, 'output':record.tea_total_kgs, 'over_kgs':2, 'scrap':3, 'pss':30.00})
tea_v = {tea_list_data}
```

Comment: The error suggests that somehow you are assigning a list as a key of the dictionary, which is not allowed in python.

Comment: What you require as an output is, comma separated dictionary values which is not a valid data structure in python.

Comment: Dear Ankit,,
please advice me to correct it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate list to get dictionary from list.

Try this:

```
for rec in your_list_of_dictionary:
    print rec #this rec variable contains dictionary
```

You can create record in every for loop instead of append the records in list.

Like this:

```
daily_transaction_master = self.pool.get('bpl.daily.transaction.master')
for record in work_update_obj.selected_tea_workers_update_line_ids:
    vals = {'bpl_company_id': record.work_id.bpl_company_id.id, 'bpl_estate_id': record.work_id.bpl_estate_id.id, 'bpl_division_id': record.work_id.bpl_division_id.id, 'worker_id': record.worker_id.id, 'date': record.work_id.offered_date, 'type':'tea', 'names': 6.00, 'output':record.tea_total_kgs, 'over_kgs':2, 'scrap':3, 'pss':30.00}
    daily_transaction_master.create(cr, uid, vals, context=context)`
```

You can do same thing in your every loop.

Comment: thanks its worked fine Arya.
any idea about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16434990/openerp-7-reports-error ?

Answer (score 0):

here is final edited code and now its worked perfectly.

```
def temp_posting(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
    tea_v = {}
    rubber_v = {}
    sundry_v = {}
    other_v = {}

    if context is None:
        context = {}
    bpl_division_id = context['bpl_division_id']
    work_update_ids = self.pool.get('bpl.work.update').search(cr, uid, [('bpl_division_id', '=', bpl_division_id)])
    work_update_obj = self.pool.get('bpl.work.update').browse(cr, uid, work_update_ids)[0]
    if work_update_obj:
        work_update_obj.write({'state': 'negotiation'})        

    daily_transaction_master = self.pool.get('bpl.daily.transaction.master')

    for record in work_update_obj.selected_tea_workers_update_line_ids:
        tea_v = {'bpl_company_id': record.work_id.bpl_company_id.id, 'bpl_estate_id': record.work_id.bpl_estate_id.id, 'bpl_division_id': record.work_id.bpl_division_id.id, 'worker_id': record.worker_id.id, 'date': record.work_id.offered_date, 'type':'tea', 'names': 6.00, 'output':record.tea_total_kgs, 'over_kgs':2, 'scrap':3, 'pss':30.00}
        daily_transaction_master.create(cr, uid, tea_v, context=context)
    for record in work_update_obj.selected_rubber_workers_update_line_ids:
        rubber_v = {'bpl_company_id': record.work_id.bpl_company_id.id, 'bpl_estate_id': record.work_id.bpl_estate_id.id, 'bpl_division_id': record.work_id.bpl_division_id.id, 'worker_id': record.worker_id.id, 'date': record.work_id.offered_date, 'type':'rubber', 'names': 6.00, 'output':record.rubber_total_kgs, 'over_kgs':2, 'scrap':3, 'pss':30.00}    
        daily_transaction_master.create(cr, uid, rubber_v, context=context)
    for record in work_update_obj.selected_sundry_workers_update_line_ids:
        sundry_v = {'bpl_company_id': record.work_id.bpl_company_id.id, 'bpl_estate_id': record.work_id.bpl_estate_id.id, 'bpl_division_id': record.work_id.bpl_division_id.id, 'worker_id': record.worker_id.id, 'date': record.work_id.offered_date, 'type':'sundry', 'names':record.sundry_hrs_worked, }    
        daily_transaction_master.create(cr, uid, sundry_v, context=context)
    for record in work_update_obj.selected_other_workers_update_line_ids:
        other_v = {'bpl_company_id': record.work_id.bpl_company_id.id, 'bpl_estate_id': record.work_id.bpl_estate_id.id, 'bpl_division_id': record.work_id.bpl_division_id.id, 'worker_id': record.worker_id.id, 'date': record.work_id.offered_date, }
        daily_transaction_master.create(cr, uid, other_v, context=context)
    return True
```